# Is it natural to say "go down on the price" meaning to reduce the price?

Tags: phrase-choice

Would you tell me if it is natural to say *go down on the price* meaning to reduce the price? For example:

> The car costs $5000 and I can't **go down on the price.**

If it doesn't sound natural, can I say *I can't go lower that price* or *I can't go under that price*? What would you say?

Comment: "**Come** down on the price" is actually a good deal more common than *go*, so much that "go down" sounds odd to me: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=come+down+on+the+price%2Cgo+down+on+the+price&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccome%20down%20on%20the%20price%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgo%20down%20on%20the%20price%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the phrase

> I can't go down on the price

sounds quite ok, while the other two options will sound better:

> I can't go lower that price

- I can't go lower than that price

> while I can't go under that price

- I can't go below that price

Comment: Or just "I can't take less".